# In CakePHP unit testing, can I use the same database for the $default and $test configurations?

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I'm new to TDD process also in CakePHP testing.

My question is, are we need to have two database which is one is for default and one more is for test ?

So let say I have `my_database` for `$default`. Do I need to use `my_database` also on `$test` ? or I need to create another one which is something like `my_database_test` ? Which one is the common?

I have read this : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html
but still didn't get any idea whether need to use different database or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, unit testing in CakePHP is not intuitive for beginners, as the purpose of the test database isn't all that clear.

Keep this in mind: **The test database is an empty sandbox whose tables are created, populated and dropped as part of the life cycle of every test.**

The test database should not contain permanent data, as it will be destroyed. Therefore, by no means you can use the 'default' database as your test database. **It's a must that you create a separate database for testing**.

To create the tables that hold the testing data, you need to define [Fixtures](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#fixtures). Fixtures can automatically import table information and data from your 'default' database with every test run. However, in most circumstances it's a better practice to hard code the fixtures manually.

Comment: Thank you that helps me but I would like to know if you are saying that I should not doing any unit testing as I'm beginner?

Comment: Nope. I haven't said that. Quite the contrary! Start unit testing as early as possible! I'm just saying that CakePHP unit testing is a common source of confusion for beginners.

Comment: @InigoFlores Would appreciate it if you could provide a patch to improve the [related](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#test-database-setup) section on manual.

Comment: @ADmad a huge responsibility, but will try :)